# File Manger Not opening for Image and Video Upload In WebView in Android 13 but working in less SDK versions

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview, android-13

I have added some code in my webView to enable file uploading. But the functions are working well in android 11 and 13. But when I try this in android 13, it is not working. The file manager dialogue is not opening.

Here is my code in MainActivity

```
package com.ucabdul.microjobs;


import static androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.MotionEffect.TAG;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progress;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    //File upload Process
    private static String file_type     = "*/*";
    private String cam_file_data = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> file_data;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> file_path;
    private final static int file_req_code = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progress.setMax(100);


        // WebView webView = new WebView(this);
//        setContentView(webView);

        //webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.ccom");




        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



        webView.setWebChromeClient( new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                progress.setProgress(newProgress);
                if (newProgress == 100){
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            // File Upload

            /*-- handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 21+ --*/
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                if(file_permission() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                    file_path = filePathCallback;
                    Intent takePictureIntent = null;
                    Intent takeVideoIntent = null;

                    boolean includeVideo = false;
                    boolean includePhoto = false;

                    /*-- checking the accept parameter to determine which intent(s) to include --*/

                    paramCheck:
                    for (String acceptTypes : fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()) {
                        String[] splitTypes = acceptTypes.split(", ?+");
                        /*-- although it's an array, it still seems to be the whole value; split it out into chunks so that we can detect multiple values --*/
                        for (String acceptType : splitTypes) {
                            switch (acceptType) {
                                case "*/*":
                                    includePhoto = true;
                                    includeVideo = true;
                                    break paramCheck;
                                case "image/*":
                                    includePhoto = true;
                                    break;
                                case "video/*":
                                    includeVideo = true;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes().length == 0) {

                        /*-- no `accept` parameter was specified, allow both photo and video --*/

                        includePhoto = true;
                        includeVideo = true;
                    }

                    if (includePhoto) {
                        takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = create_image();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", cam_file_data);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                            }
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                cam_file_data = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                            } else {
                                cam_file_data = null;
                                takePictureIntent = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (includeVideo) {
                        takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File videoFile = null;
                            try {
                                videoFile = create_video();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Video file creation failed", ex);
                            }
                            if (videoFile != null) {
                                cam_file_data = "file:" + videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                                takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videoFile));
                            } else {
                                cam_file_data = null;
                                takeVideoIntent = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    contentSelectionIntent.setType(file_type);


                    Intent[] intentArray;
                    if (takePictureIntent != null && takeVideoIntent != null) {
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent, takeVideoIntent};
                    } else if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                    } else if (takeVideoIntent != null) {
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takeVideoIntent};
                    } else {
                        intentArray = new Intent[0];
                    }

                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File chooser");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, file_req_code);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }



            //
        });

        webView.loadUrl("https://microjobs.porpop.com/");
        //


        //userAgent = System.getProperty("http.agent");
        //webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent + "yourAppName");

        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().replace("; wv",""));

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.startsWith("tel:") || url.contains("whatsapp") || url.contains("tg")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



    }



    //File Upload

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;

            /*-- if file request cancelled; exited camera. we need to send null value to make future attempts workable --*/
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                file_path.onReceiveValue(null);
                return;
            }

            /*-- continue if response is positive --*/
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(null == file_path){
                    return;
                }
                ClipData clipData;
                String stringData;

                try {
                    clipData = intent.getClipData();
                    stringData = intent.getDataString();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    clipData = null;
                    stringData = null;
                }
                if (clipData == null && stringData == null && cam_file_data != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(cam_file_data)};
                }else{
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        final int numSelectedFiles = clipData.getItemCount();
                        results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            results[i] = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Bitmap cam_photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            cam_photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                            stringData = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), cam_photo, null, null);
                        }catch (Exception ignored){}

                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(stringData)};
                    }
                }
            }

            file_path.onReceiveValue(results);
            file_path = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == file_req_code){
                if(null == file_data) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                file_data.onReceiveValue(result);
                file_data = null;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public boolean file_permission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=33 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO}, 1);
            return false;
        }if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }



    private File create_image() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    }


    private File create_video() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        String file_name    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_mm_ss").format(new Date());
        String new_name     = "file_"+file_name+"_";
        File sd_directory   = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(new_name, ".3gp", sd_directory);
    }


    //File Upload

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }




}
```

It is working in old android versions, but not working in android 13. I added new permissions for android 13 like 'READ_MEDIA_IMAGES' but still not working.

Comment: `The file manager dialogue` ? What do you consider to be that? How does one start such a 'box'?

Comment: Yes, the file manager dialogue. This file manager dialogue is not showing. I think the onshowfilechooser function has problem. Can you suggest me another way to white onshowfilechooser?

Comment: I asked what you ment with file manager dialog and you did not tell. I also asked how you opened it which you did not tell either.

Comment: In html, there is a button for upload file. When it is clicked, it supposed to open the file manager dialogue from webview. But in android version 13, it is not opening.

Comment: Without you having to code anything? Then why did you post so much code? Where is it for?

Comment: In the oncreate activity, check there is a function of onshowfilechooser. This is the part which is making problem in android 13. If you can, suggest me something.

Comment: I want to suggest all time. But if you dont tell what code exactly is not working .. i'm already waiting twelve hours.. I will not read your code before you tell..

Comment: public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)

Here, onshowfilechooser is not working, it is not opening the file chooser dialogue. I am sorry if I am unable to make you understand.

Comment: Is this function called/triggered? You did not even inform us what happens and what not happens. And if it is triggered then you did not tell which code failed. And you did not tell why your code should open a file chooser. Use Log.d() statements to see which code gets executed.